# in r convert a column of a data frame to a vector without "unlist" and with a dynamic name

Tags: r, benchmarking

I would like to convert a data frame column to a vector, where the name is dynamic.
All I know is that the I want the first column.

Now, I can do this with `unlist`, but it is about two orders of magnitude slower than accessing by name:

```
df = data_frame(x = 3, y = 4)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark({df$x}) #less than 1 microsecond
microbenchmark::microbenchmark({unlist(df[,1}) #about 15 microseconds!
```

Is there a more efficient way than unlist if I don't know the name of the column in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `df[,1]` is still a tibble with one column.

```
str(df[,1])
#Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ x: num 3
```

We need `df[[1]]` to extract the column.  So, it is doing operations in two steps, `[,1]` and then `unlist`

---

Also, if we do a `profile`ing, the `unlist` step is taking more memory and time

```
library(profvis)
df <- tibble(x = 1:1e7, y = 1:1e7)

profvis({

   df1 <- df[,1]
   unlist(df1)



})
```

[image]

```
profvis({
  df1 <- df %>%
          select(x)
  unlist(df1)

})
```

and check with

```
profvis({
    df %>%
       pull(x)
   })
```

or

```
profvis(df$x)
```

NOTE: These are too fast that they complete even before the profvis acts on it resulting in error

Comment: In my tests `df[[1]]` is slightly slower than `df$x`. But it has advantages when programming.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth also noting that `data.frame` and `tibble` differ in how they preserve the dimensions of the object. If we were to define a data frame and subset on a single column, it would return a vector:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 3, y = 4)

df[,1]
#[1] 3
```

While a tibble does not simplify by default:

```
df <- tibble(x = 3, y = 4)

df[,1]
#  A tibble: 1 x 1
#      x
#   <dbl>
# 1     3
```

If we want a tibble to simplify, we can either use `[[` subsetting to extract a single column, which does simplify into a vector, or we can specify `drop = T`:

```
df <- tibble(x = 3, y = 4)

df[,1, drop = T]
# [1] 3

df[[1]]
# [1] 3
```